# Textbox doesn't fit into division

Tags: css, html

Recently I try to fit textbox for publishing post. Main problem - textbox doesn't want to fit properly, even if it obviously should. Here is the image:

[image]

and here is the JSFiddle file I prepared for this question:

https://jsfiddle.net/Ch3shireDev/u0j5rgud/4/

It looks like a textbox is naturally expanded to the right.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.post {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* width: auto; */
  height: 300px;
  padding: 5px 5% 5px 5%;
  margin: 20px;
  box-shadow: #888888 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}

.background {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 10px;
}

.titlebox {
  height: 20px;
}

.message {
  height: 100px;
}

.background {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

textarea {
  margin: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.input {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
}

.buttons {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class=post>
  <div class=background>
    <div class=title>
      <h3>
        Publish post
      </h3>
    </div>

    <div class=input>
      <form>
        <textarea class=message cols=50></textarea>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class=buttons>
      <input type="submit" value="Preview" />
      <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

What should I do to get textbox fitting right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your textarea, just add `box-sizing: border-box;`.

```
textarea{
  resize:none;
  width:80%;
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u0j5rgud/6/

> `border-box`: The width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes content, padding and border

Comment: Thanks, it fixed my problem!

Comment: ofc, in 8 minutes, Stack Overflow doesn't allow me to do it faster.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 textarea rules in your css, try deleting the one with the wodth set to 100%

Answer (score -1):

Remove the padding from your `textarea`

```
textarea {
    padding: 0;
}
```